# Email de confirmación. PHP/BDDO

Tags: php, mysql, email

Me preguntaba como funcionan los emails de confirmación y si es posible ver algún ejemplo al respecto.

Se me ocurre dos campos en la base de datos, uno boleanos, y el otro de texto, cuando el usuario se registre, por defecto el boleano estará en false, generar una key con alguna función como rand, (a pesar de ser pseudo aleatorio) mandar la key via email y almacenarla en la base de datos, un formulario dónde verificar la key, y si hace match-up con la key de la base de datos actualizar la casilla de verificación a true.

Teniendo en cuenta que, sería absurdo crear un formulario dónde enviar los datos de la key por método get/post, se podría hacer mediante GET generando el link automaticamente. Tipo: Pagina.php?Key=27ACA373FS siempre y cuándo la sesión esté abierta.

Imagino que me dejo muchas cosas en el proceso, de ahí que quisiera saber si realmente hacer lo anteriormente dicho sería lo adecuado, o si hay otras maneras más eficientes.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

es un juego de codigos sencillos, en mi caso hice lo siguiente:

en la pagina de registro generaras un codigo aleatorio (de la longitud de tu eleccion) por ejemplo:

```
   <?php $randomnumber = rand(1000, 9999); ?>
```

esto generara un numero aleatorio de 4 cifras y lo guardara en una variable, ahora ese codigo lo puedes insertar en tu base de datos como informacion oculta dentro de tu formulario, por ejemplo:

```
            <form method="post" id="signup" action="signIn.php">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Registrate</h2>
            <input name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Max 15" type="text" maxlength="10" required="required">
                 <br>
            <input name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario Max 15" type="text" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" required="required" >
                 <br>
               <input name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="contraseña" type="password" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off" required="required" >            
                 <br>
            <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo@electronico.com" type="email" autocomplete="off" required="required">
                 <br>
            <input name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Numero telefonico" type="tel" maxlength="10" >
                 <br>
           /* valores escondidos*/
            <input name="active" id="active" type="hidden" value="false">
        <?php echo "<input name='code' id='code' value='".$randomnumber."' type='hidden'  required>"; ?>

              <button type="submit"> Crear cuenta </button>
```

como veras hay dos valores escondidos en tu formulario.

1) el codigo generado

2) el campo que dice si esta activo o no

AMBOS deben entrar como datos en la tabla de tu base de datos.

Ahora debes enviar un correo con esa informacion, puedes usar la función mail(); en la misma pagina PHP donde procesaras los datos que pasaron por POST, por ejemplo:

```
   <?php

   $id = NULL;
   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
   $code = $_POST['code'];
   $active = $_POST['active'];
   $joining_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $fecha=$joining_date;

   /*----------VARIABLES DE CORREO-------------*/

   $to      = $email;
   $subject = "Correo de Confirmacion";
   $message = 'Hola '.$nombre."\r\n"." Sigue este vinculo para activar tu cuenta"."\r\n\r\n"." http://tupagina.com/confirm.php?usuario=".$usuario."&code=".$code."\r\n";
   $headers = 'De: (tu correo )' . "\r\n" .
'Dudas y/o sugerencias: (tu correo)' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

?>

posteriormente envias el correo con :

```
  <?php
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 ?>
```

cuando la persona reciba el correo vera algo como  http://tupagina.com/confirm.php?usuario=juanito&code=1234 al hacer click le llevara a la pagina confirm.php de tu web y ahi puedes hacer la comprovacion de resultados por medio de GET y si son iguales a los de tu base de datos pues cambias la celda "Active" a "true" y listo.

es solo un ejemplo el cual a mi me funciono a la perfección,RECUERDA como tip adicional usar sentencias preparadas para evitar inyección PHP.